# MySQL involving crazy multiple self-joins

Tags: mysql, left-join, join, inner-join, self-join

As part of the process of replacing some old code that used an incredibly slow nested select, I've ended up with a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT r3.r_id AS r3_id, r2.r_id AS r2_id, r1.r_id AS r1_id
FROM
table_r r3
LEFT JOIN (
  table_r r2
  INNER JOIN (
    table_r r1
    INNER JOIN table_d d ON r1.r_id = d.r_id
  ) ON r2.r_id = r1.parent_id
) ON r3.r_id = r2.r_id
WHERE d.d_id = 3
```

So in the innermost join, I'm looking for the records in `table_r` (copy `r1`) which have a relationship with a subset of records from `table_d`.

In the next join out, I'm looking for records in a second copy of `table_r` (`r2`) whose main index (`r_id`) matches the parent index (`parent_id`) of the records from the previous join.

Then I'm trying to do a `LEFT JOIN` with a third copy of `table_r` (`r3`), simply matching `r_id` with the `r_id` of the previous join. The idea of this outermost join is to get ALL of the records from `table_r`, but to then do the equivalent of a `NOT IN` select by using a further condition (not yet in my query) to determine which records in `r3` have `NULLs` for `r2_id`.

The problem is that the `LEFT JOIN` is not giving me the whole of `table_r`. It's giving me the same subset of records that I get without the final join - in other words, the same thing as an `INNER JOIN`. So whereas I'm expecting 1208 records, I get 508.

I know I must be doing something screwy here...

Comment: Further attempt at clarity:
What I want is:

(whole of table_r) MINUS (records in table_r which are child records of other records in table_r which are linked to a set of records in table_d)

Answer (score 0):

What happens, if you try this?

```
SELECT r3.r_id AS r3_id, r2.r_id AS r2_id, r1.r_id AS r1_id
FROM
table_r r3
LEFT JOIN (
  table_r r2
 INNER JOIN (
   table_r r1
   INNER JOIN table_d d ON r1.r_id = d.r_id AND d.d_id = 3
 ) ON r2.r_id = r1.parent_id
) ON r3.r_id = r2.r_id
```

What I did was moved the d.d_id = 3 from where clause to the INNER JOINs ON qualifiers.